# Is it possible to break a script into several pods?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers

I have been trying to figure out a way to take a script that runs in a single container and break that out so that it runs in several pods.

The idea for doing so would be that currently my script runs a job and logs to a text file. The next step in the process pulls data from the log file and runs the next step then generates a new log file and so on.

The process steps its way through about 12 different steps but I need the logs for compliance and record keeping.

I want to break this process up as I am considering moving it to Kubernetes and I need to be able to have this process run on several entries but some of the steps run longer than others.

What I need to know is can Kubernetes pods take a process and send it to another pod or is there a way to spin up a pod to act as a management pod to control the process?

***Right now it looks like this:***

## = Container A =

Process A
Process B
Process C
Process D
Process E

***Future State:***

## = Container A=

Process A

## = Container B =

Process B

## = Container C =

Process C

Process A Completes and the pod dies and Process B begins picking up the log data from a PVC shared by the cluster.

Comment: This seems like it could be a good match for a job-queue system like RabbitMQ.  Kubernetes on its own doesn't deal with data or process flows like what you're describing, but pods can make HTTP requests to each other, or push and pull work via a queue that you separately install.

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for a generic workflow system, and Kubernetes is just an implementation detail. I would suggest you look at something like Airflow for starters.